# UISearchBar expands when editing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

In my UITableViewController I have a search bar that works perfectly. The only problem is when i press it to edit the search text, it automatically grows bigger, how can I disable this?
[image: before edit]
[image: when editing, the searchbar has expanded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your UIViewController in the storyboard and uncheck the option to extend edges "Under Top Bars" on the right hand side:

[image]